# Reduce the time complexity while populating data into a matrix python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension, sparse-matrix

I have a core_df dataframe. Each row has to be compared against other and the result has to be stored in a matrix. The conditions are if the start or end nodes do not match or if the length ratio is less than 0.2, 0 has to be populated else some value(say 100).
The problem is the dataframe can be huge. It can result in millions of records.
What I have done to save memory is :

- Initialise a sparse dok matrix
- Populate values only in upper diagnol matrix( as it will be mirror image for the lower)
- changed the datatype of the matrix so that it consumes less bytes.
  Any other suggestions to improve the memory allocation would be welcome.

I have tried the below code, though it is returning result, its taking huge amount of time on large dataset. Is there a way to optimise the time complexity?

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
core_df = pd.DataFrame({'sno':[1,2,3,4],'start':[1,3,5,5],'end':[5,14,17,27],'start_elements':[('A', 'B'),('X','Y'),('B', 'C'),('B', 'C')],'end_elements':[('L', 'M'),('S', 'T'),('N', 'P'),('N', 'P')]})
 
core_df_count=len(core_df)    
Score_matrix = dok_matrix((core_df_count, core_df_count))

for i in range(0, core_df_count):
    start1 = core_df.iloc[i, 1]
    end1 = core_df.iloc[i, 2]
    Start_elements1 = core_df.iloc[i, 3]
    End_elements1 = core_df.iloc[i, 4]

    for j in range(i + 1, core_df_count):
        start2 = core_df.iloc[j, 1]
        end2 = core_df.iloc[j, 2]
        Start_elements2 = core_df.iloc[j, 3]
        End_elements2 = core_df.iloc[j, 4]

        if Start_elements1 != Start_elements2 or End_elements1 != End_elements2:
            Score_matrix[i, j] = 0

        else:
            ratio = (end1 - start1) / (end2 - start2)
            if ratio <0.2:
                Score_matrix[i, j] = 0
            else:
                Score_matrix[i,j]=100
Score_matrix_2D = pd.DataFrame(Score_matrix.todense())
Score_matrix_2D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First I group df based on `start_elements` & `end_elements` and search for only such
2. In each group I calculate lengths and make dense matrix comparing lengths (ratio).
3. I search for which df indices ratio is >= 0.2
4. I do not assign 0 to sparse matrix, just 100 where it is necessary. There is 0 everywhere by default

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

core_df = pd.DataFrame({'sno': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'start': [1, 3, 5, 5], 'end': [5, 14, 17, 27],
                        'start_elements': [('A', 'B'), ('X', 'Y'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'C')],
                        'end_elements': [('L', 'M'), ('S', 'T'), ('N', 'P'), ('N', 'P')]})

core_df_count = len(core_df)
Score_matrix = dok_matrix((core_df_count, core_df_count))
core_df_values = core_df.values

for (start_elements, end_elements), group_df in core_df.groupby(['start_elements', 'end_elements']):
    lengths = (group_df['end'] - group_df['start']).values
    ratios = np.divide.outer(lengths, lengths)
    # I guess we should not take into account diagonal, so adding this:
    ratios[np.arange(len(ratios)), np.arange(len(ratios))] = 0
    where_is_above_threshold = np.where(ratios >= 0.2)
    row_indices = group_df.index[where_is_above_threshold[0]]
    column_indices = group_df.index[where_is_above_threshold[1]]
    Score_matrix[row_indices, column_indices] = 100

Score_matrix_2D = pd.DataFrame(Score_matrix.todense())
print(Score_matrix_2D)
```

```
     0    1      2      3
0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
1  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
2  0.0  0.0    0.0  100.0
3  0.0  0.0  100.0    0.0
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a ton for the great ideas. Couple of questions , 1)the real operation I have to perform at the last else part (Score_matrix[i,j]=100) is Score_matrix[i,j]= np.dot(sample_df[i,:].data, sample_df[j,:].data) . The sample_df has same no. of rows as core_df.  How do I accomodate that in this code. Also, how do I make the lower traingular matrix including diagnols to zero?

Comment: @AB6 This is not ok to ask a question and then change part of code that might require big changes in the answer. You should have included this `np.dot` operation in a question. You can make the lower triangular matrix to zero by filtering `where_is_above_threshold` (by **not** writing anything in a lower triangular part)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: ratios = np.divide.outer(lengths, lengths) is throwing memory issue when the data is huge. Trying to do the same with dok matrix, Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @AB6 it can be memory-optimized, by sorting array of `lengths` and for each length searching for span of other lengths that will have the ratio we want.  But I am afraid it will result probably in memory issue in `Score_matrix` anyway.

Comment: Score_matrix would be in Sparse format(also majority will be zeros) so that wont create an issue. Can you please elaborate  "searching for span of other lengths that will have the ratio we want"?

Comment: I am afraid there will be a lot of items in this sparse matrix. Eloborating on span thing: First you sort lengths, then, instead of checking each possible pair you search for boundary. Say we have lengths [1, 2, 3, ..99, 100]. For lets say length 5 you need to find boundary=25, every length below 25 will give you ratio > 0.2, everything above 25 will give you ratio < 0.2.

Comment: Yes as you rightly forecasted , it is resulting in a memory issue in Score_matrix. Any thoughts on fix for that?

Comment: Maybe using smaller dtype, `np.float32`, or even `np.float16`?